# Zariski topology & analytic topology of complex varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, zariski-topology

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$ a complex smooth projective variety,
$x \in X$ a closed point and $S \subset X$ a *constructible* subset containing $x$.

Recall, on $X$ we can consider two topologies:

- Zariski topology from variety structure
- classical topology; we can use analytic implicit function theorem

In more modern fashion the later topology arise as natural topology of
$X^{an}$ where there is an analytification functor $X \to X^{an}$ sending
complex varieties to complex analytic spaces, a generalization of complex manifolds;
since we assume $X$ to be smooth, in our case $X^{an}$ is a complex manifold. For core details on construction I recommend to take a look in Mumford's Algebraic Geometry I, Complex Projective Varieties [p 10].

In what follows now we not differ between $X$ and $X^{an}$ but consider
instead $X$ as uderlying set with two different topologies living on and
going to study relationship between both.
We assumed $S$ to be *constructible*, that is
$S= \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_i \cap C_i$ where $O_i$ are Zariski open and
$O_i$ are Zariski closed in $X$.

Now assume that $S$ contains an open with respect *classical analytical*
topology neighbourhood $U_{cl}$ of $x$.

Question: How to see that $S$ contains also a Zariski open
neighbourhood $U_{Za}$ of $x$? The problem is closely related to [that one.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375991/comparison-of-classical-and-zariski-topologies-with-constructible-sets)

Comment: $O_i\cap C_i$ contains an analytic open. Assuming $X$ is connected, if a rational function vanishes on that open then it vanishes on $X$. This is quite the definition of $O_i\cap C_i$ algebraic open.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can follow your last argument. Firstly we observe that
that a rational function is zero iff it is zero on $U_{cl}$. Since we assumed
$U_{cl} \subset O_i\cap C_i$ a rational function of zero iff it's zero on
$O_i\cap C_i$, so far. But from here we can only conclude that $O_i\cap C_i$
is dense in $X$. Why it should also be algebraic open?

Comment: $C_i$ is dense and closed so it is the whole of $X$.

Comment: two little remarks:

We assume $X$ connected. Could you tell me why a rational function $r$ on $X$, 
which vanishes on a classical open set $U_{cl} \subset X$, vanishes everywhere in $X$? 
I know that if $r$ is zero on a Zariski (!) open $U_{cl} \subset X$, then it's 
everywhere zero, but why $r$ is everywhere zero if it is zero on a classically 
open subset? Classical topology is much finer then Zariski.

Comment: and secondly, I understand the case $S= O \cap C$ now. What about $S= \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_i \cap C_i$
for $n \ge 2$? Could you please look through if my approach is ok? 
Since we assumed $U_{cl} \subset S$ we know that that there exist a $C_j$ with
$C_j= X$ by your argument with vanishing locus of rational functions. Otherwise a finite union of Zariski closed $C_i$ with 
$dim(C_i) < dim(X)$ cannot contain  $U_{cl}$.

Comment: Therfore assume that 
$C_j=X$ for $1 \le j  \le m \le n$ and $dim(C_i) < dim(X)$ for $m < i \le n$. Assume 
$m=1$ by taking union of $U_j$ with $j \ge m$. If $x \in U := \bigcup^m U_j$ we are
done, if not, then there exist a small classical open $V_{cl} \subset U_{cl}$
disjoint with $U$ and $V_{cl}$ is contained in $\bigcup_{i=m+1}^n C_i$, a contradiction.

Comment: It vanishes from the analytic open to the whole of $X$ by analytic continuation. $O_1\cup C_2 = \{ (x,y),x\ne 0\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$ is dense but not open in $\Bbb{C}^2$

Comment: I see, morally, that's a kind of generalization of identity theorem for holomorphic functions, isn't it? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)